# How to get total count of data from dynamodb in aws appsync for pagination?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am working on web app using aws amplify. And I am using Appsync GraphQL as web server.
But I don't know a  way to get a total count of data from Dynamodb through aws appsync.
Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How weird this can feel when coming from a SQL background, there is no easy way to do this in DynamoDB. The suggested approach is to perform multiple Scan operations until reaching the end and record the `scannedCount` value as you go.

You won't be able to achieve this in AWS AppSync natively, if you absolutely need to do this through AppSync you can use a Lambda resolver that will perform the `Scan` operations.

You could also keep track of all the `PutItem` and `DeleteItem` operation on your table using DynamoDB streams and increment/decrement a counter somewhere. Again this might be fragile if your Lambda ever loses track.